# Error with a "returnUrl" in URL params

Tags: php, url, yii

I am working with the Yii Framework.

In a controller, after a model save, I'm trying to redirect the user to `/module/controller/action` and set a parameter (redirectUrl) to another URL. Here is my code:

```
$this->redirect(array('/module/controller/action/', 'redirectUrl'=>'/index.php/some/url/id/'.$id));
```

This seems to work well as I am redirected to:

```
http://localhost/index.php/module/controller/action/redirectUrl/%2Findex.php%2Fsome%2Furl%2Fid%2F11
```

But when I get there I get the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL
/index.php/module/controller/action/redirectUrl//index.php/some/url/id/11 was not found on this server.
```

The URL like `/index.php/module/controller/action/redirectUrl/1234` works fine.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, URL seems to be correctly encoded. Any idea would be of great help!

Thanks

Comment: It seems the double forward slash is an issue, maybe try removing the first forward slash of the redirect url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example URL is only passing `1234` as the parameter, not a full relative URL, e.g. `/index.php/some/url/id/1234`.  I think what you want is:

```
$this->redirect(array('/module/controller/action/', 'redirectUrl'=>$id));
```

You could skip the URL rules on your server and minimally reduce load with:

```
$this->redirect('/module/controller/action/redirectUrl/' . $id);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('/module/controller/action/', 
array('redirectUrl'=>'/index.php/some/url/id/'.$id));
```

If this does not work do

```
$this->redirect($this->createUrl('/module/controller/action/',     
array('redirectUrl'=>$id));
```

and then just add '/index.php/some/url/id/' in the action.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail